# Calculating vector area in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, vector, area, viewshed, vectorization

I have calculated a viewshed (ZVI) in OpenWind and opened the raster in QGIS

I have then converted the raster to a vector

When I open the attribute table there are 4682 rows (features) and there is a column titled 'DN' and each row contains a number between 1 and 10, also 4681 rows long

When I add an $area column to work out the area of the viewshed, each row says 'NULL'

I am simply trying to calculate the area of the viewshed in metres

I am not sure why there are so many rows or why the area returns as 'NULL'?

Comment: what projection is the data in? Have you created a new column to calculate the area? The column you add should be a decimal with at least levels of precision (ie: two decimal places).

Comment: I have set the CRS to British National Grid. I have created a new column using the field calculator $area function.

Comment: Is the field a double?

Comment: Sorry, i'm not sure what that means?

Comment: When you make your new column, what type do you set it as? (ie: text, integer, double, etc.). This will have a great impact on the calculation, as it can not be calculated on some data types. The default is text, which wouldn't work.

Comment: I have reconverted my raster layer into a vector and I don't know why but I am now getting numbers in my $area column. I have used the Basic Statistics function to calculate the sum of the $area column as it is 4682 rows long. Is this correct? Thanks for your help

Comment: I can begin to comment if something is correct without seeing the data